# Button not responding in tab fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my app, I have three tabs. In each tab, I have a few controls. When I tried to implement the onClick method for my buttons, I found the buttons not responding to hand gestures, more specifically, the clicks.

Here is the class for the tab:

```
package com.telkitty.myPetProject

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.provider.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

public class ContactPage extends Fragment {

    private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;  

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Activity activity = getActivity();

        if (activity != null) 
        {       
            addListenerOnButton();      
        }   
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_page, container, false);       
        return view;
    }


    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();


    }


    public void addListenerOnButton() 
    {   
        Button add = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  
                    Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
            startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);  
        }});
    }

}
```

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


   <Button
        android:id="@+id/edit_button"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/edit_contact"/>

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/add_contact"/>



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contact_list"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:paddingTop="50dp" >

    </ListView>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: No error, it runs, just the code inside onClick never gets called.

Comment: It seems the buttons are not responding to clicks - the button is not intercepting the click actions.

Comment: You try to anonize yourself, but your code prevents you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it just happens my buttons were actually beneath the ListView, so although they looked as if they were there, everytime I clicked on them, the ListView was actually selected.

I added the marked line, now the button is working as it should.

```
   public void addListenerOnButton() 
    {   
        Button add = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        add.bringToFront(); // <--- this line
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  
                    Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
            startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);  
        }});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your views in the `onCreateView(..)` of your `Fragment` and register the listeners as followed:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_page, container, false);
        Button lEditButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_button);
        Button lAddButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        ListView lContactList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_list);

        lEditButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        lAddButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        lContactList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }
```

Implement the `onClickListener` and `onItemClickListener` interface:

```
public class ContactPage extends Fragment implements onClickListener, onItemClickListener {
```

By using these interfaces you will be forced to override the `onClick(View v)` and `onItemClick(..)` where you can handle your actions for the buttons and list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried your code, but the button is still not responding to the click.

Comment: Are controls in tab fragment acting differently?